# Recently updated to android studio 2.1.2 but it is throwing gradle build error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating the studio to 2.1.2 the class path updated to  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'. My problem is when ever i run the project it will throw below error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\abc\app\libs\jsoup-1.8.2.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: the file is there or not?? have you checked??

Comment: Ya it is there i cheked

Answer (score 0):

You need update your Android Studio to latest version for fixing this issue.
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html